# По русскому 5, по математике 4, по географии 4, по физике 3

Tags: тире

Можете сказать, какой вариант правильный? Мне кажется, что 2-й.

1. – Что у тебя за ОГЭ?
   – По русскому 5, по математике 4, по географии 4, по физике 3.
2. – Что у тебя за ОГЭ?
   – По русскому – 5, по математике – 4, по географии – 4, По физике – 3.

Answer (score 0):

Меня немного корёжит, что ответ в диалоге не начинается с новой строки, но я бываю на сайте от силы раза два в году, потому и не приучен к подобному.
Касательно вопроса. Первый вариант совершенно корректен, второй, как мне кажется, тоже. Да даже в случае моего второго абзаца, я мог бы, например, вместо точки поставить двоеточие или тире, и оба этих варианта тоже были бы верные, ибо правила русского языка допускают авторское оформление во многих своих составляющих.